# find_or_create_by with similar named attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, models

I am running a script that has updated data for models in my rails app. Each source has a slightly different name for their record and when I run find_or_create_by it of course makes a new record if the attribute used (name in this case) doesn't match. I am currently on the path of using gsub to standardize the naming before it hits find_or_create_by but I was curious if there was a better way to do it. I played around with 'fuzzy_match' but I am not sure how to incorporate this.

Comment: Rule number one for data processing: Garbage in, garbage out.

If you don't have a reliable key, then you'll generate crappy data. Isn't there a way to add a proper id or email to the data that is imported by the script?

Comment: The only thing tying all the different sources so far is the name which as mentioned is slightly different per source. I will see about trying to add another identifier though. That is a good idea.

Comment: Adding a proper unique ID is the only way this will work reliably. Otherwise you will need more than just a name (there are quite some "Christian Müller" in Switzerland or "Steve Miller" in the US...) How would to tell them appart by just the name?